# Alertdialog closing automatically after seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have implemented a Alertdialog, but this dialog closes automatically after 1 second. He doesn't even pay attention to the buttons, but simply closes automatically. I can't find the error in the code, do you perhaps know where my error is?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText name = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("Message");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        builder.setView(name);

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                Button btnOK = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                Button btnCancel = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String name = name.getText().toString();
                        if (name.isEmpty() || name.matches("")) {
                            name.setError("ERROR");
                        } else {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
                            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            editor.putString("NAME", name);
                            editor.apply();
                            //Switch to next activity
                        }
                    }
                });
                btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Can you see anything in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

#### What is wrong?

---

There is nothing wrong in the code. But I have a suspicion on the code you have given.

#### How to correct?

---

Instead of adding clickListeners on `btnOk` and `btnCancel` inside the `onShownListener`, you can add then outside the `onShow` method. It will not make any difference but I feel that that was closing the dialog.That is why I feel you shall try what I have mentioned.